# Generic Methods and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Lets say class C and D extend class B which extends class A

I have a methods in class E that I want to be able to use either an object C or object D in.  I know that class A provides all the methods that I need.  How can I go about writing a method that lets me pass either a object C or object D as a parameter?

Am I right in thinking I need to make a generic class?  If so does anyone have specific examples that are closer to what I need that [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) which only seems to tell me how to use the existing collection class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class A {
  public String hello(){return "hello";}
}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends B{}
```

The method `hello` is available in all subclasses B,C and D.

So in E, do something like:

```
private void test() {
  System.out.println(hello(new A()));
  System.out.println(hello(new B()));
  System.out.println(hello(new C()));
  System.out.println(hello(new D()));
}

public String hello(A a) {
  return a.hello();
}
```

and you can pass instances of A,B,C or D

BTW - generics are not necessary in this scenario (as far as I understood it)

Comment: Oh, well that is actually how I had it set up already, cool.  I am not at a stage where I can test the code yet so just wanted to check.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `C` and `D` have `A` as their common ancestror and `A` provides all needed methods, then your method should simply take an instance of `A` as a parameter. You do not need a generic method, unless I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void doSomething(A input) {
  input.methodInA();
  input.secondMethodInA();
  ...
}
```

Polymorphism will run an possible overridden code implement in C or D, you don't need to do anything other than call the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A { 

}

class B extends A { 


}

class C extends B { 


}

class D extends B { 

}

class E { 

    public void test ( A a ) { 
        // c or d will work fine here
    }

}
```